# Как можно выполнять/вызывать функции javascript?

Tags: android, javascript, webview, функции

Как в Android в загруженной WebView можно выполнять/вызывать функции javascript?

Answer (score 2):

По идее, если в вашем JavaScript'е есть функция типа:

```
<script>
function myFunction(message)
{
    alert("Message: "+message);
}
</script>
```

То ее вызов из Android'а должен выглядеть так:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction('Hello World!')");
```

Comment: то, что вы написали:
<script>
function myFunction(message)
{
    alert("Message: "+message);
}
</script>
это где хранится и если у меня  webview уже загружен html код, то это выполнится дополнительно к этому коду? т.е. все ранее загруженное останется?

Comment: Ну конечно, речь идет о Javascipt'е уже загруженном в `myWebView`, то есть скрипт уже должен быть "внутри" WebView - иначе как он выполнится?

Comment: Поняла) спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @Barmaley, Все же получается когда я загружаю код html и потом вызываю функцию, то полностью опять весь код перегружается. 
А мне поверх выполненного кода выполнить функцию...

Comment: Попробуйте поиграться с методом `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`

Comment: @Barmaley, что-то я не пойму как мне это метод может помочь...

Comment: @Мария_1 ну вы поройтесь в доках по `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` - я вам дал хинт, а уж дальше поработайте сами, включите мозги, гугланите - в общем отрабатывайте свой хлеб :)